# Сохранение файла в папку с нынешней датой

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `ок` в `saveFileDialog` создавалась папка с нынешней датой и туда сохранялся файл с нынешней датой. При сохранении выбивает ошибку:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Users\Андрей\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\2016.10.16".

```
 private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
     String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
     string path = @"C:\Users\Андрей\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\" + date;

     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
     if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {                
         DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
         string path_c = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
     }
     richTextBox1.SaveFile(date , RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вы сохраняете документ по пути из переменной `date`. Во-вторых, где именно выбрасывает исключение: на вашей машине разработчика или на машине пользователя? Полагаю, второе. Ну так простому пользователю разрешён доступ только к специально выделенным папкам.

Comment: 1) Разве чтобы оно сохранило в папку с нынешней датой не нужно путь + название папки с такой же датой ?(звучит, конечно, дико). 2) На моей машине разработчика.

Comment: Да, нужно. Но вы не используете `path` и `path_c`. Смотрите вызов `SaveFile(date `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать этот код в обработчике вашего пункта меню:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Получаем текущую дату в кратком виде с учетом формата даты системы
        string filedate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        //Путь к EXE файлу:
        string basepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        //Получаем новый путь, состоящий из пути к исполняемому файлу + папка с текущей датой:
        string newpath = Path.Combine(basepath, filedate);

        //Проверяем, не создан ли данный путь в предыдущие запуски программы.
        if (!Directory.Exists(newpath))
        {
            //Путь пока не создан... 
            try
            {
                //Пытаемся создать папку:
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                //В случае ошибок ввода-вывода выдаем сообщение об ошибке
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //Вновь генерируем обшибку. В случае необходимости реакцию на ошибку ввода-вывода
                //можно изменить именно тут:
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                //В случае ошибки с нехваткой прав вновь выдаем сообщение:
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //И вновь генерируем ошибку. Если нужно обработаь ошибку более детально, то тут как раз
                //самое место это сделать. 
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        //Создаем дисалог сохранения:
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

        //Начальная директория диалога - наша папка с датой.
        sd.InitialDirectory = newpath;

        //Имя файла по-умолчанию в диалоге сохранения делаем в виде дата + время, 
        //при этом заменяем симовлы двоеточия (они не допустимы в имени файла) на дефис "-".
        //Получится, например, так: 27.10.16_14-33-01
        string filename = filedate + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().Replace(':', '-');
        sd.FileName = filename;

        //Задаем фильтры по-умолчанию для диалога (настройте, как нужно):
        sd.Filter = "Текстовый файл (.txt)|*.txt|текст в формате Unicode (.txt)|*.txt|Rich Text Format (.rtf)|*.rtf|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";

        //Выбираем из фильтров формат RTF:
        sd.FilterIndex = 3;

        //Заголовок диалога сохранения:
        sd.Title = "Укажите имя файла для сохранения:";

        //Показываем диалог и обрабатываем результат:
        if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Так как через диалог пользователь мог выбрать совершенно другой путь и имя файла - 
            //получаем путь для сохранения файла именно из диалога:
            string newfilename = sd.FileName;

            //Обрабатываем выбранный в диалоге тип файла:
            switch (sd.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1: //Текстовый файл
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(newfilename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    break;
                case 2: //Юникод-текст
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(newfilename, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
                    break;
                case 3: //RTF
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(newfilename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                    break;
                default: //По-умолчанию RTF
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(newfilename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. Использовать русские символы в названии методов, студия, конечно допускает, но правила хорошего тона говорят, что вместо `private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click` лучше использовать примерно такое имя метода: `private void SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click`.

Comment: да имя ToolStripMenuItem само генерится по тексту, если поменять забыл - получай вот такое имя метода. Вот тут-то и заметишь, но поменяв имя ToolStripMenuItem  имя обработчика не изменится. Решаемо, но досадно...

Comment: Ваш код работает, спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей, пожалуйста! Рад, что помог!

Answer (score 3):

1) Не понятно зачем вы отображаете пользователю SaveFileDialog, если потом никак не используете путь и имя файла получаемые через это диалог. Таким образом вы вводите в заблуждение пользователя вашей программы. Но если вам не нужен выбор пользователя просто используйте кнопку, кот. сохранит и оповестит об успешном сохранении файла с помощью `MessageBox`.
2) для определения каталога в кот. работает текущая программа существует несколько способов, вот один из них: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, полученный таким образом путь следует объединять с именем файла с помощью `Path.Combine()`

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы  вместо имени файла указываете директорию.

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(date , RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

В данной строке, `date` = имени дирректории. Имя файла так у вас и не задано.

```
private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        // Получили путь
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"));
        // Создаем папку
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        // Вызываем диалог сохранения, для чего там он вам нужен
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
            // Получаете текущий католог
            string path_c = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            // Наверное используете как вам надо
            // И тут еще куча кода
        }
        // Формируем имя файла
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + ".rtf";
        // Потом сохраняете в файл с таким же именем как и текущая дата
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(Path.Combine(path, fileName) , RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
```